# getPivotCacheDefinition return null value when Refresh Pivot Table with Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table

I want to refresh pivot table after enter data to data sheet

I read two previous questions [this][1] and [this][2]. there two way to do this

one way is

Right click your pivot table -> pivotTable Options -> Data -> Check Refresh Data when opening File

this is working I want a automated way so I tried in this way

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Summary");
XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.getPivotTables().get(0);
pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true);
```

I have two pivot tables in this sheet so `sheet.getPrivotTable` return this

```
[Name: /xl/pivotTables/pivotTable1.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.pivotTable+xml, Name: /xl/pivotTables/pivotTable2.xml - Content Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.pivotTable+xml]
```

but `sheet.getPivotTables().get(0).getPivotCacheDefinition()` return null value.

Is there any way to refresh Pivot table automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the `XSSFPivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition()` does not work properly when `XSSFPivotTable` was read from an existing `*.xlsx` file. This is because of the kind how the `XSSFPivotTable` is got form the file. See [XSSFSheet.read](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_0_FINAL/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.java?view=markup#l225): The `XSSFPivotTable` is read from the related document parts of the sheet. But the `XSSFPivotTable` has relations of it's own. But those are not read at all.

You could file a bug report to `apache poi` about this.

Workaround: The `XSSFPivotTable` extends `POIXMLDocumentPart` and so it knows about it's own related document parts where the `XSSFPivotCacheDefinition` is one of.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelReadPivotTables {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  XSSFWorkbook workbook = (XSSFWorkbook)WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWorkbook.xlsx"));
  XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("Summary");

  System.out.println(sheet.getPivotTables());
  if (sheet.getPivotTables().size() > 0) {
   XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = sheet.getPivotTables().get(0); 
   System.out.println(pivotTable);

   XSSFPivotCache pivotCache = pivotTable.getPivotCache();
   System.out.println(pivotCache); // null!
   XSSFPivotCacheDefinition pivotCacheDefinition = pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition();
   System.out.println(pivotCacheDefinition); //null!

   for (org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart : pivotTable.getRelations()) {
    if (documentPart instanceof XSSFPivotCacheDefinition) {
     pivotCacheDefinition = (XSSFPivotCacheDefinition)documentPart;
     System.out.println(pivotCacheDefinition); //not null!
    }
   }
  }
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: I try to refresh pivot table using this pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true) but it do not refresh pivot table.

Comment: @heshjse: What do you mean by "it do not refresh pivot table"? The `pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true)` sets a marker in the `*.xlsx` file to force `Excel` to refresh the pivot cache while opening the `*.xlsx` file. This is what this marker does, nothing else.

Comment: I added pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true) but still pivot table not refresh while opening*.xlsx file.

Comment: @heshjse: Sorry, I cannot reproducing. Just tested. For me `pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true)` works as expected. Of course if the source data range also has changed, then this also needs to be set: `pivotCacheDefinition.getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheSource().getWorksheetSource().setRef("A1:X100")`. Where `A1:X100` is the new source data range.