# Apache POI PivotTable - Change AreaReference dynamicaly

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I have created XLS with 2 sheets - `pivot` & `raw data` sheet with required format & pivot table definitions in Excel.

I am using POI to fill data in `raw data` sheet from database & download from application.

```
/* Get the reference for Pivot Data */
            XSSFSheet pivotSheet = xwb.getSheet("Pivot_1");

            if (pivotSheet != null) {
                XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.getPivotTables().get(0);
                if (pivotTable != null) {
                    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().setRefreshOnLoad(true); // java.lang.NullPointerException
                    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getPivotArea(xwb); // Get AreaReference
                }
            }
```

My question is: Is it possible to update AreaReference for existing PivotTable in excel based on data sheet max number of rows.

Comment: The code you are showing cannot throw that exception. If `pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition()` throws `NullPointerException` then  `pivotTable` must be `null`. But `XSSFPivotTable pivotTable = pivotSheet.getPivotTables().get(0);` cannot result in `pivotTable` == `null`. Please show the exact code which leads to the problem.

Comment: @Axel: I have edited question with full code block & exception thrown line.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53735734/getpivotcachedefinition-return-null-value-when-refresh-pivot-table-with-apache-p/53743342#53743342 for how to get `XSSFPivotCacheDefinition` from `XSSFPivotTable`.

Comment: Thank you Axel, I am able to get XSSFPivotCacheDefinition & update RefArea dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

My pivotTable is based in table and update AreaReference with:

AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("B1:J" + rowIniCount + 2, SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
XSSFTable table = sheet.getTables().get(0);
table.setCellReferences(areaReference);